# Blazor webassebly to update model triggered by the server

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

I am trying to build a Blazor webassembly with a .net core server.
My server has to communicate with a PLC to get some data. 
In an MVC application, I would have to make a call to update the data every 1 seconds. 
I am looking for a better way to do this with Blazor. The server and client share the same model.
I am not sure how to do this nor if it is possible. 
Ideally, the server would update the model and trigger an ever that the client would receive and update its model. 
Any idea how to do this or if it is possible?

Thank you and have a great day!

Comment: Don't you just update the Blazor Server model, and the diffing algorithm just sends the updated model to the rendered client over websockets (signalR)? All this is pre installed with Blazor server.

Comment: that worked great. Thank you. I am new to blazor and have not used signalR before.